# Is it appropriate to edit answers to add evidence?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Frequently, I have seen comments to the tune of "This answer is great, but it should have included [x] source, which states [evidence]" on well-voted answers.

If we assume the well-voted answer is well-accepted for the question, would it not benefit the answer in the long term to add [evidence] to the answer via the suggested edit / full edit function?

I ask this because I frequently see the former, but have not seen the latter often.

Comment: no because it changes the authors intent of the answer

Comment: The intent of the author is to not provide evidence?

Comment: Would it be appropriate to do so in the case of an answerer saying: "The official documentation states [y]", but not containing the actual quote from the documentation?

Comment: Yes, and that's what I do. It is also a good edit to link to the documentation.

Comment: @LutzHorn Sometimes, yes.  Sometimes it's just a distraction and is unnecessary.  Keeping answers focused and on point is often important.  Sometimes citations and more rigorous proofs of a point are needed (when they're central to the answer and unlikely to be understood by the reader), and sometimes they are just taking attention away from more important points.

Comment: @nostalgk That's a case where a citation is important for it to not be plagiarism.  If you're quoting something, you need to properly cite it.

Comment: When it comes to editing answers, I take one thing to heart above anything else: *I am flawed*. Who says the edit I am making to someone else's answer is not adding a mistake, a mistake which can then add potential downvotes on the plate of someone who didn't do anything wrong? At this point in your Stack career your edits still need to be reviewed so its easy to think "ah, if I goof up someone will catch it". But that is too naive, reviewers will likely just reject the edit for the reasons given here already. Me, I stick to editing answers to make them better readable, and no more.

Comment: There is precedence for this, the Documentation project failed badly.  Big problem was that users just didn't know when to stop adding more stuff.  Exactly when an answer doesn't have enough so would benefit from an edit is pretty subjective.  If it goes over, say, 5 paragraphs then it gets to be too much.  Nothing wrong with comments that provide supplementary info.

Comment: @Gimby even if you are flawed, who says that you cannot be right on this one? Remember, authors are *always* notified of edits to their posts.

Comment: This question is great, but it should have included a link to a example answer, which states the type of comment you are referring to

Comment: Adding a link to official documentation is fine, and in most cases there's not much point in actually embedding the linked material in a quote. Let the interested reader browse the docs themself.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - **To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place**
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - **To add related resources or hyperlinks**

https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Also, note that the list is not exclusive, there are other reasons for edits.

Comment: That third point is mostly philosophically what I'm getting at with my question; my interpretation is that answers should aim to be complete, as comments are transient. Of course, I'm new here, so I'm trying to get a good idea of how things work. Thanks for including relevant sources in your meta-answer!

Comment: @nostalgk note however that while reviewers are happy to **approve 1-2 characters edits that do change the meaning** of a post, they also reject edits with large swats of red and green that doesn't change said meaning.

Comment: FWIW, even though suggested edits can sometimes be a waste of time, I'd definitely be appreciative of somebody who took the risk to add references in. There's been many times where a post pulled information out of seemingly nowhere that I would have liked to read more about (or read the original statement that the source gave) but couldn't.

Comment: It would've been wittier to just answer "yes" and wait for another user to edit in the quote from https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing. A missed opportunity!