# Is adding a link to a more explanatory answer a valid edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I encountered a different sort of suggested edit and I'm curious about the community's opinions about this kind of thing.

On a succinct accepted answer to an old question, someone had suggested this edit adding a link to a different answer to the same question that offers a more in-depth explanation:

```
For an explanation of when and why this works, see
[the details below] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/link-to-other-answer).
```

with this edit summary:

> Cross-reference this answer with the other answer that explains more deeply.

(Just to clarify, the edit was *not* suggested by the author of the linked answer.)

While I can see how the edit was intended to be helpful, my initial assessment was to reject it as "clearly conflicts with the author's intent", assuming that if the author had intended to add more in-depth explanation, they would have done so, and if readers weren't satisfied with the level of explanation in that answer, they would probably just scroll down and see what else was there anyway.

Am I correct in assuming that this type of edit intended to increase the visibility of another answer isn't really appropriate, or is this too strict an interpretation of "conflicts with author's intent"? Could it potentially be a valid/useful edit? Does this depend on the quality and accuracy of the two answers?

I don't see anything in the [edit help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) that specifically says not to do this, and I can see how it could be interpreted as a combination of a couple of the "common reasons to edit" listed there.

I haven't linked to the edit suggestion because I'd like to avoid getting bogged down in the details of a specific example and stay focused on the broader question. And I ended up skipping the review, for what it's worth (I skip a lot) but I'd like to see what y'all think about it.

Comment: People can scroll. Unless the answer is to a different question, the link is superfluous.

Comment: If the user that wrote the answer added the link, it's fine. If someone else added the link, I'd be very tempted to revert the edit.

Comment: In the past, I've seen this kind of thing a good idea when there is a bilateral benefit in answers linking to each other. As an example, `This is "in-place" / "not in-place" solution, for the alternative see here[link].` This can help a visitor understand the nuance of an answer without having to trawl through dozens of solutions and possibly make mistakes.

Comment: I'd reject this edit as well. While the other answer and the link may actually be helpful this should not be part of another's authors answer. It could however be a very helpful comment to the initial answer.

Comment: @TinyGiant do you mean that you'd also reject the edit, but as "no improvement" rather than "conflicts"?

Comment: While I generally agree that links to another answer on the same question are probably unnecessary (unless the question has 5 pages of answers or something), I'm a bit concerned about the thought process behind "...assuming that if the author had intended to add more in-depth explanation, they would have done so," and it kind of reads like you're saying that editing in references is never OK, which [is explicitly called out as a valid edit reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370878/4975230).

Comment: @jrh hmm, I didn't intend for it to come across that way, but I see what you mean. I'll try to think of a better way to phrase that.

Comment: @Don'tPanic either would be applicable IMO.

Comment: It seems to me a situation like this would warrant checking whether one or the other question should be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: @CindyMeister In this case the link was to a different answer on the same question. If that was not the case, I definitely agree.

Answer (score 11):

This is noise and should be rejected/edited out for a couple reasons:

1. It could be spam; is the person who added the link to the answer the one who wrote the other answer being linked to? Do they have some relationship with them?
2. Even if there's no conflict of interest as in point #1, it could still be underhanded; if the user posted the "Share this Answer" link rather than an anonymized one, then if enough people click the link, the editor will get a badge or badges. I would say that linking to your own content on the same page this way constitutes abuse (however mild).
3. Even if cases 1 and 2 are not met, it's still unnecessary: links are typically for navigating away from the page you're on to a new one (anchors notwithstanding), and Stack Overflow conveniently includes a working y-axis scrollbar to allow us to scroll up and down the pages. It even lets us sort answers by a few different ways to help show different answers higher than others given different circumstances.

I would always be wary of someone other than the poster editing in a link to another answer; I can't think of a situation where that should be done as an edit rather than as a comment, and even as a comment, a link is unnecessary; just say "this is explained further in X User's answer above/below."

Comment: While I agree that the link in a comment is *unnecessary*, it can be quite useful, particularly when there are a number of answers. Having a link allows the user reading the comment to jump directly to the linked answer, rather than having to go searching for it. Frankly, I'd feel that I'd been a bit inconsiderate if I didn't put such a link in, if referencing another answer. Ideally, it would be just a `#fragment` link, but SE doesn't create links for bare `#fragment` URLs (i.e. `[this answer](#123456)` doesn't create a link). Thus, use the full question URL with the answer fragment.

Comment: @Makyen I don't think the link is any more useful than scrolling anywhere from zero to half a dozen scrolls on a middle mouse wheel.

Comment: Well, it could become ambiguous if the user changed their name

Comment: I occasionally put links to others' answers into my own answers, both to credit them and to avoid repeating what they already said.  Of course, this makes sense only when I think there is more to be said about the subject than the other answerer already wrote.  But I wouldn't edit someone else's answer to link to a third party's.

Comment: I'd say editing in a link to your own answer, into somebody else's answer on the same question is a bit suspicious, but I'm not so sure about the other cases. Maybe I just haven't seen it on the tags I read but I have a hard time imagining somebody would go through the trouble of editing in links just for the sake of getting a badge or to pump up a friend's post. Also note that "see Joe's post above" isn't a great navigation comment because post scores can change or somebody could be sorting by most recent / some other metric, plus accounts can get deleted and IIRC usernames can change.

Comment: Also I had no idea the "share" link was personalized and counts toward the "announcer" series whereas the straight link doesn't, I figured it was just a shorter link that helped me reduce my character count in comments. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @jrh just because they are two different accounts doesn't mean they are two different people. User as account 1 posts answer then as account 2 edits a link to account 1's answer into highly rated answer. Profit

Comment: @JohnBollinger If you're doing it in your own answer, it's different, and probably benign; my answer is tailored to 3rd parties editing answer-links into other peoples' answers, which is what the question is about.

Comment: Reject the comment based on the quality of the link and its relation to the material in the answer, no other reason.

Links are often recommended by many people on SO as a way to provide reference or give additional information.

Comment: @Andrew No, you should take a more holistic approach than that; context matters.

Comment: @TylerH, there's no way to guess or divine the intent of another user. How would someone be able to effectively govern based on your first two points? The only way I know how to do this is based on the relevance of the link to the original content.

Comment: @Andrew There are a lot of things you can consider in addition to the link itself, chiefly who posted it? Was it Person X adding a link to their own answer? That's underhanded; it gives the impression of the post author giving credence to a potentially competing answer. Is the link really that necessary that simply scrolling down to it is not enough, and you need a permanent (read: not a comment) link to *another resource **on the same page*** in the answer? Situations where that is warranted are vanishingly slim.

Comment: @Andrew Additionally, edits to others' posts should strive to maintain the author's intent and/or respect their agency. If the author wants to point to another answer, let them do it. If you think they should, suggest so in the comments. If you think another answer is relevant or helps better explain the contents of an answer, say so in the comments. None of these situations call for or demand that a *link* edited into the answer.

Comment: @TylerH... I don't think who adds the link is as relevant as the information itself. OP said the link provided additional information. Was the linked answer one of 3 or one of tens or one of hundreds? Was it highly informational with relatively few upvotes? If it was relevant and added to the conversation then it's useful.

Comment: @TylerH, Can you say that in this situation the author's intent was not respected?

Comment: @Andrew Based on OP's description, the author's agency was *not* respected because of the underhanded (whether it was intended that way or not) way the link was worded and introduced. While we cannot know of any ulterior motive without an admission from the editor, it's at least almost never necessary (and I would argue simply never) to link to one answer from another in the same question, period. It's *certainly* worth extra investigation when it's a separate user editing someone else's answer to link to a different answer on the same page. And without saying what the link is to, to boot.

Comment: @Andrew It could be that you just don't see much abuse or bad behavior either by being a low-activity or low-rep user on the site/network, but it happens, and this is something we should easily be able to draw a line on and say, don't do it unless you need to. Users have many better ways to share the information than to change someone else's answer to link to a competing answer, especially considering potential fraud situations, which users and elected moderators can't necessarily readily detect.

Comment: @TylerH... I see a fair share of abuse as I am a regular on this site. Most of it is from highly experienced users of the site who treat newbs poorly. I'll finish this dialogue by saying that if someone has enhanced the ability to gain access to useful information that is relevant and substantively helpful then it's worth keeping. OP didn't say the linked answer was wrong or against the ideas of the author. Indeed, the author will still get credit for the answer. If the link contradicted the author then remove it. Okay. I'm done. I'll read any other comments but probably not comment anymore.

Comment: @Andrew Abusive behavior toward other users is not what I'm talking about; I'm talking about abuse of the system. And yes such a blanket statement of 'improvements are good and should be kept' is easy to defend, but the thing is such an edit is *not* really an improvement, and, what you seem to keep missing/ignoring, it *needs* to be coupled with the consideration of *why* the user opted to make that edit rather than simply comment, which is a much more appropriate way to convey that information.

Answer (score 1):

From your description of said "edit", it sounds like it would have been more appropriate to leave a "comment" appended to the accepted answer instead.

The criteria for comments is that they can be used to point out problems with an original post.  In this case, the problem may have been that another StackOverflow user felt the accepted answer did not fully address the context of the question being asked.

Answer (score -2):

If the link:

- Is Valid
- Relates to the material
- Furthers the answerer's response by adding additional detail or context
- Adds new information

Then it should be accepted because it is useful.
However, if the link is not relevant, or does not add new information, to the material at hand, then it should be rejected.

If the link is relevant but different from the answerer's response, then move it to a different answer.

Links should only be judged on the merit of their contribution to the discussion.

---

**EDIT**

I'm including this [link from SO META](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253804/update-guidance-for-how-to-answer-to-improve-answer-quality) about how to improve the quality of answers. The highest voted answer suggests including references. [This answer includes a link to SO suggestions about how to answer questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) that suggest including external references and providing context for those references.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please comment why you downvoted, otherwise the reason for your downvote will have no recourse to be addressed, and SO misses the chance for us to have a meaningful discussion.This is also a recommended practice.

Comment: Regarding your edit: "external resources" are resources outside the Stack Exchange site network, not competing answers on the exact same question here on Stack Overflow. The suggestions in the Help Center say that if you are going to add a link, make sure to provide useful context to avoid the famous link-only problem, which helps prevent information loss due to link rot.

Comment: Re: commenting on downvotes as a recommended practice: that is completely and utterly false. Comment on content and vote on content; dont comment on votes. The standard reason for a downvote is that the voter thinks the content is not useful.

Comment: @TinyGiant, I believe you have incorrect information though perhaps you haven't seen the explanation in this link in a while since you're far above 2K experience
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes/2373#2373

Comment: @TinyGiant... Unfortunately, people downvote for a variety of reasons. The link above illustrates a few of those down voting habits and how often they don't relate to the actual quality of the answer, but more to someone's mood.

Comment: @Andrew I'll call your Atwood and raise you a Shog9: [No. Explaining votes is almost pure noise, meta-conversation and punditry. Your votes are your own to do with as you please; you owe no one an explanation, nor is a discussion of your voting habits likely to be helpful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777/4639281)

Comment: Sure... Shog9 disagrees. That's not my point. Plenty of people disagree. I'm getting at the underlying falseness of your original statement regarding commenting on downvotes. I have shown that it is recommended and that there is a feature in place to remind users to do that.

Comment: Also... having just downvoted on an answer in Stack Exchange, the forum reminded me that it would be useful if I left a comment on why I downvoted. It was automatic. It was recommended, by the site. And, I did leave a comment as to why I downvoted, because why wouldn't I?